# How to get logged in use and protect urls in jwt token auth django REST framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I have working auth token , working for users on my database at django back end its pretty simple setup using django rest framework and jwt token module. Here is my settings module

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
            'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
                'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
            ),
            'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
                'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
                'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
                'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
            ),
        }
        INSTALLED_APPS = [
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'constants',
            'rest_framework_jwt'
        ]

        MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
            'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        ]
```

But know I want my some of my url to authenticate using this token and get to know the logged in user but can't get the materials to do that.

any help .